# Logging the model data from the POST request body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-post, modelstate

My requirement is to log the model data that I am receiving from a POST request. but when I am tring to get the values from ModelState.Values, I am not receiving anything. I also tried to Log Request body, but same with the request body also, I am not receiving any data.

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Send([FromBody]RequestDto model)
    {
        return CreateResponse(() => _sendTask.Send(model, false));
    }

[ApiController]
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    #region Protected methods

    protected IActionResult CreateResponse()
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
               foreach (ModelStateEntry values in ModelState.Values)
               {
                  value.Append(values);

               }

               return BadRequest(value.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogCritical("Exception occurred during processing of a request", ex);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What is this Send([FromBody]RequestDto model) for ? I  can not see how it is used.

Answer (score -1):

When we received a post request which contained data in request body, I don't think we can get the value from `ModelState.Values`, you may see screenshot below, `ModelState.Values` doesn't contain data, we need to get data from the Model itself.

[image]
[image]

Another example, see my following screenshot, when I send such post request to my api, I can see data in my model but no data in request body or modelstate.value

```
[HttpPost]
public void getModel([FromBody] Movie model) {
    var request = HttpContext.Request.Body;
    if (ModelState.IsValid){
         var value = ModelState.Values;
    }
    var a = model.Price;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, How can I get RequestDto model data and use it inside my APIController and log the data there. APIController is a base controller and all the other controllers are inherting from it. I want to Log all my model data there.

Comment: You can't get the data in your `RequestDto` ? Any error messages? And how you send your request? I think you may refer to my code sample and do a simple test....